# System.InvalidCastException during FindByText in dropdownlist

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind a dropdown to a table in sql-server. Binding is working correctly and values are displayed in dropdown.

But when I try to select a record whose value is null for that dropdown and try to load controls, it gives me a System.InvalidCastException exception.

here is my code -

```
   If Not ddlTaxRate.Items.FindByText(dr("TaxRate")) Is Nothing Then
         ddlTaxRate.Items.FindByText(dr("TaxRate")).Selected = True
   End If
```

It throws this exception on FindMyText

> Additional information: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

How to make sure that null value can also be selected?

Answer (score 0):

A `NULL` is not a value. Its a mark of a missing value.
You can handle `NULL` in your database query itself when binding the dropdown.

```
SELECT ISNULL(TaxRate,'') AS TaxRate
```